# Error when inserting figure in latex (Thesis)

Tags: floats, errors

I am writing a thesis on the latex file provided by the university. And I cannot insert the figure, there are 3 errors when compiling. Here is the short version of the latex file:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{thesis}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{pifont}
\makenomenclature
\renewcommand{\nomname}{ABBREVIATIONS}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{picinpar}
\usepackage{epic}
\usepackage{eepic}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{xy}\xyoption{all}
\usepackage{morefloats}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\selectlanguage{english}
%\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[subfigure]{tocloft}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}    %
\usepackage{flushend}    %
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{siunitx}   %
\usepackage{mathtools} %

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}\centerline{\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{1.png}}
    \caption{State feedback via communication network}
    \label{fig}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Here are the errors:

[image]

After reading some of the similar questions, from understanding these errors occurs in thesis latex templates. Someone suggested to use xcolor package instead of color, which I tried and it failed. Then I have removed xcolor and color, again the same mistakes appear.

Comment: Unrelated: Note that with a few exceptions, the `hyperref` package should always be the last package loaded as it has to adjust it self to a lot of other packages.

Comment: Is there a link to that `thesis.sty` file? Without it we cannot test your code. Without it, the example compiles just fine. Note: don't load packages that you don't use.

Comment: @daleif I think I downloaded everything from here: https://github.com/fcyu/HKUST_PhD_MPhil_thesis_Latex

Comment: This version of `thesis.sty` (1) rather old, (2) redefining several macros in away that is probably not compatible with current LaTeX. Since we know the issue is figure related, I out commented the `\def\@xfloat` redefinition. Without this redefinition, the example compiles just fine.

Comment: You can place `\makeatletter
\let\normal@xfloat\@xfloat
\makeatother
` before loadading `thesis` and `\makeatletter
\let\@xfloat\normal@xfloat
\makeatother` after, in order to restore the normal `\@xfloat`. Then you don't have to change anything in `thesis.sty`.

Comment: If this is an official setup provided by the university, ask them to update it. If it is just something that some one put together, you are probably better of not using `thesis.sty`

Comment: @daleif "not compatible with current latex" is putting it mildly: the float definition is based on latex2.09 so it has been incompatible with latex since 1993.